# How to take permission for creating contacts group?

Tags: google-shared-contacts

I want to create contact group for user.  I am using oauth 2.0.
I have added 'https://www.google.com/m8/feeds'  scope also.

Below is my code.

```
contactService.setAuthSubToken("access Token");
```

But i am getting below exception.

```
<p>Your client does not have permission to get URL <code>/m8/feeds/groups/abc@xyz.com/full</code> from this server.
<ins>That&#39;s all we know.</ins></p>
```